# Making a table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
>    [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/2975)

I want to insert a table in my LaTeX document but the problem is when I insert it it isn't placed where I want and I don't understand why this happened.  This is the code:

```
\section{Simulations et Résultats}
  Tout au long de cette section nous allons faire différentes simulations en modifiant à chaque fois un paramètre pour voir l'impact de cette modification sur la propagation des données. 
  \subsection{La création des réseaux:}
  Nous allons présenter les différents réseaux crées ainsi que leurs caractéristiques.
  \subsubsection{Réseau 1:}
  Les deux tableaux ci dessous résument les caractéristiques du réseau 1. En effet les deux réseaux crée présentent les mêmes caractéristiques sauf que le premier réseau est moins connecté que le deuxième:

  \begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
  \hline
 \bf Nb Pages Totales & \bf Nb Pages Publiques & \bf Nb Pages Amis et leurs Amis & \bf Nb Pages Amis Seulement& \bf  Nb Min amis & \bf  Nb Moy amis & \bf  Nb Max amis \\
  \hline
  1.1 & 11 & 2&17&11&25.7&60.8 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\caption{Caractéristiques du Réseau 1.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the _position specifier_? See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Floating_with_table

Comment: In short `table` is a "float", i.e. it is not connected to the text but floats until it finds a good location to be placed. This is standard in high quality publications like books. See the above linked threads to find the possible ways to influence the position.