# The place of my table

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

My problem is that my table isn't insert in the right place despite I specify when I would like to place it. This is my code:

```
\subsubsection{* Réseau 3:}
Nous allons maintenant partager la publication dans le réseau 3. 
\paragraph{Page ayant le nombre minimal d'amis:}
Pour ce type de page nous allons partager la même publication avec les dix pages qui ont le nombre minimal d'amis dans le réseau.

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
%\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.3cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
  \hline
 \bf Id Page  & \bf Politique de Partage & \bf Nombre Amis & \bf Nombre Pages qui ont reçu la pub \\
  \hline
   156 & Amis et leurs Amis & 64&237 \\
   231&Amis Seulement&66&66\\
   124&Amis et leurs Amis&67&217\\
   182&Amis Seulement&68&68\\
   70&Tout le Monde&68& 250\\
   241&Amis Seulement&68&68\\
   102&Amis et leurs Amis&68&233\\
   171&Amis Seulement&68&68\\
   59&Tout le Monde &69&250\\
   81&Amis et leurs Amis&69&209\\


   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Moyenne des pages qui ont reçu la publication }&7

    \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bf {\caption{Publication partagée avec une page ayant un nombre minimal d'amis dans réseau 3}}
\end{table}

\paragraph{Page ayant le nombre moyen d'amis:}
Pour ce type de page nous allons partager la même publication avec les dix pages qui ont le nombre moyen d'amis dans le réseau.
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
%\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.3cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
  \hline
 \bf Id Page  & \bf Politique de Partage & \bf Nombre Amis & \bf Nombre Pages qui ont reçu la pub \\
  \hline
   42 & Tout le Monde & 42&250 \\
   83&Amis et leurs Amis&82&245\\
   109&Amis et leurs Amis&82&220\\
   141&Amis et leurs Amis &82&235\\
   153&Amis et leurs Amis&82&249\\
   209&Amis Seulement&82&82\\
   218&Amis Seulement&82&82\\
   141&Amis et leurs Amis&82&244\\
   5&Tout le Monde &82&250\\
   56&Tout le Monde&82&250\\


   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Moyenne des pages qui ont reçu  la publication }&210.7

    \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bf {\caption{Publication partagée avec une page ayant un nombre moyen d'amis dans réseau 3}}
\end{table} 
\paragraph{Page ayant le nombre maximal d'amis:}
Pour ce type de page nous allons partager la même publication avec les dix pages qui ont le nombre maximal d'amis dans le réseau.
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} 
%\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.3cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
  \hline
 \bf Id Page  & \bf Politique de Partage & \bf Nombre Amis & \bf Nombre Pages qui ont reçu la pub \\
  \hline
   161 & Amis Seulement & 101&101 \\
   137&Amis et leurs Amis &99&237\\
   243&Amis Seulement&98&98\\
   44&Tout le Monde &98&250\\
   133&Amis et leurs Amis &97&214\\
   8&Tout Le Monde&97&250\\
   188&Amis Seulement&96&96\\
   20&Tout le Monde&95&250\\
   53&Tout le Monde&95&250\\
   11&Tout le Monde&94&250\\


   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Moyenne des pages qui ont reçu la publication} &199.6\\ 


    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bf {\caption{Publication partagée avec une page ayant un nombre maximal d'amis dans réseau 3}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Does one of these questions help you: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275) [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) [How to fix table position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9485)

Comment: The question looks to me _very_ similar to one of your former (closed) questions: [Making a table in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53111)

Comment: @Thorsten: but my code contains when I would like to insert my table

Answer (score 6):

Specifying `[h]` is too restrictive for LaTeX, it will convert it automatically to `[ht]`, that is, it will place the table [here] if possible, or [at the top of the current/next page] if not. That is why you can't find a way to put the table where you want it!

A table is a float, and when compiling, LaTeX uses a lot of constraints regarding floats. One way of ignoring those constraints is to put a `!` before the desired position. In your case, it would be `\begin{table}[!h]`. Although this will make LaTeX ignore the constraints as much as it can, it will not necessarily make your float appear where you want it to.

For more information please visit [this webpage](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/latex-floats/)

I hope it helped.

Comment: @ wiwh: I traied with [!h] but the problem isn't resolved what do you say is right because the table cannot be place where I want because there is enough place

Comment: Please if someone have an answer he tell me

Comment: If this didn't help you, the problem is out of my league. I would be interested in a general answer to this problem, though!

Comment: there is something wrong and illogical because I enforce Latex to place the table but it doesn't consider it Please compile my exemple and you will understand please I'am blocked

Comment: @boutheina Your "example" cannot be compiled because there are missing several required parts like `\documentclass{...}` or `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`

Comment: @Thorsten:thank you very much for your  interest but I resolve my problem my code was right just I must add the new page because the place isn't enough for it